# Django-ckeditor how to set RichtextField to plain text as default configuration?

Tags: python, django, django-ckeditor

Ckeditor erase my uploaded SVG tags whenever I save the fields on my admin page.

I would like to keep my Ckeditor as plain text on the admin rather than clicking on "source", how should I configure it ? I haven't found anything about that on their documentation.

Here is the only configuration I have :

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
}
```

Comment: Try checking this section of the documentation called 'Example CkEditor Configuration'. It has some config options listed. This helped me when I was implementing it for my site.
https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#id18

Comment: @DeA checked it nothing shows on the config about setting the ckeditor to plain text

Comment: @DeA Sorry, I think there is a misunderstanding, plain text == source, I want to show nothing just text so my SVG text don't get erased

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming when you say:

```html
{{object_list.description|linebreaks}}
```

instead of this just wrote

```html
{{object_list.description|safe}}
```

this will solve your problem